# Chemfig error: illegal parameter number in definition of \CF@compound

Tags: chemfig

I'm using the Chemfig package version 1.2e

I copied the `\chemfig{A-#(,0pt)B-#(0pt)C}`
command from the manual to the editor, but the execution results in an error.

I need to adjust the length of the bonds.

The option "shorten" works good with simple and "<:" bonds, but not with "<" bonds.

How to solve?

Comment: with v1.6a works fine

Comment: i'm using the default opensuse leap 15.3 packages. To install version 1.6a I will need to search the internet.

I work around the problem by using a long invisible bond to the atom and a shorter, visible A<B bond over the previous bond.

Comment: @EdsonMarcon Managing LaTeX install with the distro package manager is a giant headache, *especially* on the LTS-type distribution that Leap is. I strongly advise to use vanilla TeX Live installer and `tlmgr` package manager. Alternatively, have a look at [TinyTeX](https://yihui.org/tinytex/) – this [should ease the pain](https://yihui.org/tinytex/pain/) of getting working and fine-tuned TL and is beneficial if you are an R user.

Comment: @andselisk -- That worked really well, thanks.